# Mouseover over touching interfaces

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

I mean android, ios, etc.

While there's no solution / replacement for mouse over on those interfaces, how can we gather all those relevant infos, for instance from stack exchange, while navigating through them? In SE case, it becomes even more relevant when you want to grab the tags info. But I mean in general, for any website.

Should we consider making a complete different style to accomodate this specific lack of info on ipads?

Is there already any good solution for this?

Comment: Supposedly this is one reason why mr. jobs won't allow flash onto his hardware - no way to "hover" on an element.

Comment: something about that title creeps me out

Comment: @Cheese I think it's the "touching" feeling over over you. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using jQuery to create a click event that is an alternative to the normal mouseover event, In the example a tooltip is inserted after .tooltip on a normal mouseover event.

```
/**
 * when tooltipss are clicked trigger their mouseover event then fade the tooltip
 * (this is friendly to touch interfaces)
 */
$('.tooltip').click(function(){

    $(this).mouseover();

    // after a slight 2 second fade, fade out the tooltip for 1 second
    $(this).next().animate({opacity: 0.9},{duration: 2000, complete: function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    }});

});
```

The idea here is to show the tooltip for a few seconds  and then have it fade naturally. But in general all you need to do is have the click event call the mouseover event and then do something to remove the tooltip when you are done with it.

Comment: Do you mean the element that creates the tooltip, or the tooltip itself? If the element that creates the tooltip is already clickable then I guess I didn't fully understand the original question. If you are talking about having clickable elements on the tooltip itself then you just don't have the tooltip go away until you are done using it.  The most basic point here is just that you have your click event call your mouseover event, the rest is details.

Comment: I just realized you might also be trying to say that your element has a tooltip on mouseover, and another function entirely on click, well in that case I would move your original click event to a new click event that happens on the tooltip itself. This could be by default, or again use jQuery to add this functionality when you need it.

Comment: If you hover the tags on SO with your mouse and then try to see that same thing on an iphone you'll see what I mean - like I said in the question. But moving the click to the tooltip is quite a nice idea. Or even just making it click a second time on the element itself, once the tooltip is opened. Hopefully every "touching interface" will be able to handle jQuery! :)

Comment: You might want to check http://jquerymobile.com/ out as well. I've been meaning to look into it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about other approaches, but what i have done to facilitate non visual browsers is to have a button that when the mouse is over it shows a tooltip and when clicked or pressed shows a messagebox with the same information as the tooltip. Keep in mind "messagebox" does not have to mean the ugly alert box it can be custom. the thought being the alert allows screen readers etc to know about the additional information being provided.