# Mouse-over and clickalble horizontal submenu?

Tags: html, css, submenu

I've a good menu with a mouse-over horizontal submenu, but on my iPad I can't do mouse-over in  the Chromebrowser. So you can't open the submenu because it is mouse-over.

How to make the menu mouse-over and clickable? (submenu will open when you hold your mouse on a tab and when you click on a tab)

Comment: check these links,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885554/mouseover-on-touch-screen

Comment: This also   http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mouseover over touching interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277257/mouseover-over-touching-interfaces)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna give these options a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such event in touch devices (smartphone and tablets) as `mouseover` nor `mouseout`.

There are events like `touchstart`, `touchend` and `touchmove` but they're corresponding to *desktop*'s `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove`.

When you put your finger on a touch screen, it's like you'd already *mousedown*'ed it.